# Определить,что проскроллилили именно до этого блока?

Tags: javascript

Есть лендинг, на нем есть определенная секция. мне нужно отследить момент, когда пользователь оказался на этом блоке. Проскроллил до него. как это можно определить?

Comment: как вариант взять расстояние от верха страницы блока, который нужен `$(block).offset().top` и значение на сколько проскролили сверху `document.documentElement.scrollTop`. и если расстояние на сколько проскролили близко к `$(block).offset().top` значению значит он виден.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('block');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  const posTop = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  
  // Блок достиг верхней границы экрана (или выше)
  // elem.classList.toggle('visible', posTop <= 0);
  
  // Блок только появляется снизу (или выше)
  // elem.classList.toggle('visible', posTop < window.innerHeight);
  
  // Блок целиком находится в видимой зоне
  elem.classList.toggle('visible', posTop + elem.clientHeight <= window.innerHeight && posTop >= 0);
});
```

```css
#block {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 400px 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#block.visible {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

Для того, что бы отследить только первый раз:

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('block');

document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

function onScroll() {
  const posTop = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  
  if(posTop + elem.clientHeight <= window.innerHeight && posTop >= 0) {
    elem.classList.add('visible');
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  }
}
```

```css
#block {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 400px 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#block.visible {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

Comment: а если нужно один раз отследить этот момент,а не каждый раз visible? (пишу на реакте)

Comment: @werty, `.visible` тут используется только для наглядности, ключевое тут - условие. Добавил в ответ вариант с проверкой первого появления (опять же, достаточно просто поменять условия в `if(...)`

Comment: а зачем условие positionTop >= 0

Comment: @werty, эти условия взяты из примера без "определения первого вхождения", там это надо было, что бы класс убирался когда блок выше окна уходит. Для единоразового срабатывания не нужно. Я бы скорее взял второй вариант, который `posTop < window.innerHeight` для вашего случая ну или что-то типа `posTop < window.innerHeight / 2`.

Comment: понятно. спасибо!