# Как отследить момент, что пользователь доскроллил до определенного блока

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Нужно отследить один раз, что мы доскролили до определенного блока.
Зашли на страницу, доскролили до этого блока  -- отправили данные один раз. Перезагрузили страницу,снова доскролили до блока - снова отправили данные . Один раз.

Продолжение вопроса [Определить,что проскроллилили именно до этого блока?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717068/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0/717077#717077)